# How to make pre initilized text appear in Tkinter Entry widget?/ How to set limit of number of same windows open?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Q1) I have a Entry widget and I want it to be per-initilized with a value and I want the user to have the open to erase that value and type in what ever value they want.

So for example:
Year: `2016`      <----- By deafult 2016 is already inputted and visible

Is there a way I can do this?

Q2) Is there a way I can set a limit to the number of a same window that can be opened? For example: If i have a drop down menu which has a "help" option. Currently the way I have it set up, if I click the help once the help window will pop up, and if I click it again (while the first window is still open) another help window will pop up. How do I set it so that only 1 help window can be opened at a time?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you can use a string variable

```
self.example = StringVar()
self.example.set("put what you want it to say at the start here")
#note put this before you make your entry
self.example_txt = Entry(self,textvariable = self.example)
self.example_txt.place(row = 1, column = 1)
#note iv purposely missed out class declaration ectra as i am assuming you already have that)
```

2) there is probably a better way to do this but you could use a global variable which is set to false when the help button is clicked and set back to true when help window closed

```
global valid
valid = True
#not put this at start of your program
def opennewindow():
  global valid
  if valid == True:
      valid = False
      #put code for opening new window here assuming you already have that code as 
      #you haven't asked for code for that

def closewindow():
    global valid
    valid = True
    self.master.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert something into an entry widget you can use the `insert` method:

```
e1 = tk.Entry(...)
e1.insert(0, "hello, world")
```

To only allow a single help window, create the help window once and hide it. Then, make your help function merely show the window rather than create it. Or, have the function check to see if the window exists; if it doesn't, create it before making it visible.

Comment: I tried using windowName.withdraw() and windowName.deiconify(), but i get a error saying "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'deiconify'"

Comment: @JohnDoe: well, that error is telling you that you called `deiconify` on a function rather than an object. `deiconify` and `withdraw` work.

Comment: Wierd, i used deiconify on my TopLevel widget name. I have it as a global variable because I call deconify in another definition. This is probably causing the problem?